# How to programmatically create a new Page in MoinMoin?

Tags: python, moinmoin

I want to write a python script that calls some external REST service and then creates MoinMoin pages based on the data that I pull back. I am using Python 2.4.3 on CentOS 5.3 and MoinMoin 1.9.3 in a wiki farm configuration.

Note I don't want to embed data in pages using Macros, as I already know how to do that. I want to create a Page from a Template if at all possible without the user having to do anything.

Can anyone post some example code, or links to example code, on how to go about programmatically creating a Page in MoinMoin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a documentation of the MoinMoin API: http://moinmo.in/MoinAPI/Beispiele

It is in german (the main MoinMoin developers are german).

I think what you want is the PageEditor: http://moinmo.in/MoinAPI/Beispiele#PageEditor