# MoinMoin - Upload Wiki with python script. No GUI

Tags: python-2.7, https, postman, moinmoin

What I have:

0) A python script using requests that fetched all the data from old WIKI. (ask me for it if you want)

1) A "download"-folder. In there are saved the wiki markups as .txt files.

2) Name of the file: wiki/page1 is used to make wiki__page1.txt . 
(each "/" is replaced by a double "_" to make usable file names.

3) A Wiki_Move_Final.txt which is a file which contains the name of all the pages I would like to move, one newline per page.

4) 600 files in all. Many of them underpages (wiki__page1__underpage1.txt)

What I am trying to do:

4) Upload all of this knowledge to a new WIKI which already has pages and a structure. Keep the structure of the old pages.

5) With a python script, using .requests.

Here my script so far. The result is that it creates folders on my browser with an edit-lock file in them.

```
DESTINATION_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/"
with open('not_found.txt', 'wt') as log:
    for line in open('Wiki_Move_Final.txt'):
        line = line[:len(line)-1]
        try:
            filename = os.path.join('download',      line.replace('/','__')+".txt")
            with open(filename,'rb') as payload:
                data = {
                    # "action" : "edit",
                    # "button_save" : "Save Changes",
                    # "category" : "",
                    # "comment" : "Upload of old wiki",
                    "rev" : 0,
                    "savetext" : payload,
                    # "editor" : "text",
                    # "ticket" : "005523d9d8.baed4a026ea626e287ed81245b934103095698a4",
            }
                # cookies = {
                #   "MOIN_SESSION_8080_ROOT": "458d90bcdbd098f26bff25931f9d603c28ef14c4",
            # }
                headers = {
                    # "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            }
                url = DESTINATION_URL + line + "?action=edit"
                requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
        except IOError as e:
            log.write('%r %s\n' % (line, e))
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Joker !
I found this, which seems to do smth similar, but doesn't solve my problem yet =)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468588/how-to-programmatically-create-a-new-page-in-moinmoin